# Notepad++ custom language how to only highlight if comment keyword has a space

Tags: notepad++, batch-file

In the custom language editor in Notepad++, I recreated the batch language syntax highlighting, as I saw it as poorly made. 
My issue is that in making a remark with `rem`, I cannot have words like `remember` or `remove` without them being highlighted as well.

As shown here;
[image: Example of remark 1]
Lines 8, 9, and 11 work as desired, but 12, 13, 14, and 15 are not.

I tried adding single quotes around each including a space, but it then counted the single quote as its own comment, and broke the single behavior of the original keywords, as shown in the edit here;
[image: Example of remark 2]

Any help is appreciated, or even a guide in the right direction.